# How to fix Google Extension scrollbar disappearing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I am working on a Google Extension. The logic of the extension is same with Google Translate extension. When I select a word, scrollbar disappear on some websites such as Youtube, Stackoverflow etc. But not on Facebook or Instagram.

Did someone have such problem before? How can I solve this issue?

I tried overflowY: scroll, but didn't work.

I use React.js and Material UI.

Comment: did you try `overflowY` or `overflow-y`? The latter is correct. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y).

Comment: @Kelly I tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work...